# Passing Javascript an Empty Variable

Tags: javascript

How do I tell Javascript to use zero as a variable if the passed variable if empty?  In PHP I can use the following.

```
<?php
   function test($var=0){
      echo $var;
   }
?>
```

So it would set $var to 0 if the passed variable was empty.  I can't seem to figure this out in Javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you call a method without providing a value for one (or more) of the arguments, those arguments will be `undefined`.

Thus within the method you can test whether the variable is defined, and if not assign it a default value:

```
function test(arg) {
    if (typeof(arg) === 'undefined') {
        arg = "default"; // or whatever default value you want
    };

    // Rest of method
}
```

It's not very elegant, but Javascript doesn't have a nice native default-arguments syntax.

Comment: Works great.  It's a shame it's not very elegant as you put it, but it does the job.  Thanks!

Comment: `var` is a reserved keyword! your example will generate a syntax error.

Comment: Very true Salman - I was mirroring the PHP example in the question but that's not really an excuse for illegal syntax!  I'll update it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the or operator to do this a bit shorter;

```
function myFunc(var)
{
 var = var || 0;
}
```

Comment: What if `var` is the boolean value `false`?  Or an empty string?  Or the integer `0`?  Or *any other "truthy" value provided by the caller*?

Answer (score 2):

It strongly depends on what *empty* means for you and what values the argument is allowed to have.

An often used shortcut is

```
param = param || 0;
```

This will set `param` to `0` whenever [`param` evaluates to `false`](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_9.2).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function myFunc(var) {
   if (null == var)
      var = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Strictly that only works because of type coercion, which isn't entirely what's required.  `var` is not `null` if it's unprovided, it's `undefined`.  Your code here would assign the default value even if the caller passed in an explicit value of `null`, which is not as I understand the requirement.